# How to invoke a class in jsp if condition is true?

Tags: class, jsp, if-statement

I wrote a class for sending sms through gmail in java now I want to invoke SMS class in `user.jsp` page using if condition.
For example

```
if(dat.equals(due_date)){
  // SMS Mail = new SMS();
}
```

I included page of SMS class call constructor but I have no idea how SMS class send sms if

```
if(dat.equals(due_date)){}
```

then what syntax will come in `if {} empty braces`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html) instead of **Scriplet**.

Read official oracle document on [JavaBeans Components in JSP Pages](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro11.html) for better understanding.

### JSP - JavaBeans

A JavaBean is a specially constructed Java class written in the Java and coded according to the JavaBeans API specifications.

Following are the unique characteristics that distinguish a JavaBean from other Java classes:

- It provides a default, no-argument constructor.
- It should be serializable and implement the Serializable interface.
- It may have a number of properties which can be read or written.
- It may have a number of "getter" and "setter" methods for the properties.

The useBean action declares a JavaBean for use in a JSP. Once declared, the bean becomes a scripting variable that can be accessed by both scripting elements and other custom tags used in the JSP. The full syntax for the useBean tag is as follows:

```
<jsp:useBean id="bean's name" scope="bean's scope" typeSpec/>
```

Here values for the scope attribute could be page, request, session or application based on your requirement. The value of the id attribute may be any value as a long as it is a unique name among other useBean declarations in the same JSP.

---

Find complete sample code here on [JSP - JavaBeans](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_java_beans.htm)

Read more about [JSTL Core c:if Tag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_if_tag.htm) that evaluates an expression and displays its body content only if the expression evaluates to true.

Comment: you are right but my project is jsp base and i am just calling only one class in my jsp page please if help me in jsp related problem because i have short time to submit thanks.

Comment: what is the issue in `SMS Mail = new SMS();` code? are you getting any exception. have you used `import` page directive to use this class in JSP? or use fully qualified class name.